# Should I use "standalone", "independent" or "ad-hoc"?

Tags: word-choice

In my task-management application tasks are grouped inside "processes".
I just added support for tasks not related to any specific process and trying to come up with a right name for them.

What would be the best way to refer to such tasks in help and user documentation?

1. Standalone tasks
2. Independent tasks
3. Ad-hoc tasks

Or maybe some other word?

Comment: I'd go with "standalone" - "ad hoc" means "made up as you go along" or "unplanned" which isn't quite right here I think.

Answer (score 2):

**Standalone** *(alternate spelling variant of **stand-alone**)* — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stand%E2%80%93alone)

> self-contained; especially :  operating or capable of operating independently of a computer system
>   *"a stand–alone word processor"*

A lot of dictionaries show examples in *computing*. **Independant**, works too.